# java.lang.NullPointerException error after reading data from Excel using Apache poi

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

In the following below code after reading data from Excel when I try to insert that field value in to UI textbox it is throwing error as `java.lang.nullpointerexception`.

In the below code when I try to read the values from Excel by keeping syst.out it is showing me the correct values.

I am facing issue at this piece of code

```
      Cell=ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getCell(0);
      Cell1=ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);

      String Celldata=Cell.getStringCellValue();
      String Celldata1=Cell1.getStringCellValue();
      System.out.println(Celldata);
      System.out.println(Celldata1);
      System.out.println("username value");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      ****driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(Celldata);
```

I am getting syst.out for Celldata and Celldata1 and then after when I am trying to insert the Celldata value to Email field am getting this error.

My complete code:

```
public class NewTest {

 public WebDriver driver;

 private static XSSFSheet ExcelWSheet;

    private static XSSFWorkbook ExcelWBook;

    private static XSSFCell Cell;
    private static XSSFCell Cell1;

    private static XSSFRow Row;

@Test
public void f() throws Exception {
 // This method is to set the file path and open the excel file

  try{
  WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
  //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("http://gmail.com");
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  FileInputStream Excelfile=new FileInputStream("D:\\TestData\\Login.xlsx");
  ExcelWBook=new XSSFWorkbook(Excelfile);
  ExcelWSheet=ExcelWBook.getSheet("Sheet1");

  } catch (Exception e){
      throw(e);
  }

// This code is used to read data from excel file

  try{

      Cell=ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getCell(0);
      Cell1=ExcelWSheet.getRow(1).getCell(1);

      String Celldata=Cell.getStringCellValue();
      String Celldata1=Cell1.getStringCellValue();
      System.out.println(Celldata);
      System.out.println(Celldata1);
      System.out.println("username value");
      Thread.sleep(2000);
      ****driver.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys(Celldata);
      driver.findElement(By.id("next")).click();

      driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(Celldata1);****


  }catch (Exception e){
      throw(e);
  }

 // This code is used to write data to the excel sheet

  try{

      Row=ExcelWSheet.getRow(1);
      Cell=Row.getCell(2,Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if(Cell==null){

          Cell=Row.createCell(2);
          Cell.setCellValue("Pass");

          FileOutputStream fileout=new FileOutputStream("Login.xlsx");
          ExcelWBook.write(fileout);
          fileout.flush();
          fileout.close();
          }}catch(Exception e){
          throw(e);


      }
```

Answer (score 0):

At http://gmail.com the input field for password is not present at once. That is why 
`driver.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys(Celldata1);`
raises the excpetion.

It might take a while for the password field to appear after you have filled in the email adress. Best way to wait for it is like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30); //30s timeout
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("Passwd")));
```

If you have entered an unknown email adress (from your Excel file) the password field does not appear, at all. In that case, change your test data or insert some `if` statement in your code.